# Hierarchical policies / requirements in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET Core Identity and have the following requirements defined:

```
public sealed class IsCustomerUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement

public sealed class IsSuperUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
```

With the following basic handlers:

```
public class IsCustomerUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsCustomerUserRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsCustomerUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(_ => _.Type == "customer"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class IsSuperUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsSuperUserRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsSuperUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole("super_user"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I can then put these inside basic policies:

```
        services
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MustBeSuperUser", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IsSuperUserRequirement()));
                options.AddPolicy("CustomersOnly", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IsCustomerUserRequirement()));
            });
```

And apply it using `[Authorize("CustomersOnly")]`, which works fine.

***My requirement*** is to be able to allow super users, claim principals with the `super_user` role but *without* the `customer` claim, to also access Customers Only areas.

I have currently implemented this by changing the handler to manually check:

```
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsCustomerUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(_ => _.Type == Claims.Customer) ||
            context.User.IsInRole(Roles.SuperUser))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

***My issue*** is this feels like I'm missing the point. Is there a better way to define this so I don't have to repeat the super user check in each handler in future?

---

The bigger picture in all this is I use IdentityServer4 (ASP.NET Identity-backed) to Authenticate, and then intend to use some JWT-based claims (one claim, two roles) to further identify the user Authorisation falls into an application-specific roles / permissions structure and some custom middleware that has nothing to do with Identity Server. What, if any, best practices are there around this topic?

Comment: I find that the new policy based way of doing authorization in netcore to be a bit unfriendly when having fine-grained authorization. We ended up implementing a custom action filter (inherits `IAsyncActionFilter`) to handle authorization, and give a bit more flexibility than using those policies, which need to be set at startup. One do not want to have X variants of the same policy, due to simple variations in what claims the user has.

Comment: @scheien If you would have multiple variants of the same policy, then you are using policies and requirements incorrectly. A policy should require a set of requirements. Those requirements can (individually) be fulfilled by various combinations of claims which would then be up to requirement handlers to figure out. But this will not make policies more complex. – Feel free to post a question outlining your exact situation and I might be able to help you streamline it to fit the new model. The ASP.NET Core auth stack is actually very clean and powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*“this feels like I'm missing the point”* – Yes, in a way you are missing the point. You are doing *role* based authorization: A user can be a customer or a super user.

But instead, the new model is claims based authorization where the user has a claim about something, and you are using that to authorize them. So ideally, the super user would get the same claim the customer gets, and is allowed access to the resource that way. Such a claim also wouldn’t be called `customer` then, but be rather something that is a property of the user.

You can still use a role-based authorization model with claims but you should probably avoid *mixing* them. As you noticed yourself, this gets a bit weird eventually.

That being said, there are multiple ways to succeed a policy using different requirements. If you were using roles only (instead of that `customer` claim), you could simply use the built-in way:

```
options.AddPolicy("MustBeSuperUser", policy => policy.RequireRole("super_user"));
options.AddPolicy("CustomersOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("customer", "super_user"));
```

That way, the `CustomersOnly` policy would be fulfilled by both `customer` and `super_user` roles.

Since you aren’t using a role for your customers, you will have to follow your requirements implementation here. The way authorization requirements work though is that you can have multiple handlers for the same requirement type and only one of them needs to succeed (as long as none *fails*) for the requirement to be successful.

So you could have your `IsSuperUserHandler` handle multiple requirements. YOu can follow the [`AuthorizationHandler<T>`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationHandler.cs) implementation to make this work:

```
public class IsSuperUserHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public virtual async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        foreach (var req in context.Requirements)
        {
            if (req is IsSuperUserRequirement || req is IsCustomerUserRequirement)
            {
                if (context.User.IsInRole("super_user"))
                    context.Succeed(req);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So your `IsSuperUserHandler` is now an authorization handler for both the `IsSuperUserRequirement` and the `IsCustomerUserRequirement`. So the `CustomersOnly` policy that requires the `IsCustomerUserRequirement` will also be fulfilled for super users.

Comment: The reason `customer` is a claim is because it has a value of the customer Id (the user is associated with a customer, part of his identity). The final solution about `IsSuperUserHandler` won't work because of multiple inheritance. I did try adding the two requirements to the policy instead but that didn't work as intended (none of my handlers explicitly fail, but it still didn't satisfy the policy). I don't want to bake all the claims into the user token, and my claims would end up being synonymous with granular permissions :-(

Comment: I agree with you main point though, my disjointed feeling is because I'm mixing two concepts.

Comment: Sorry about that, for some reason I thought the requirement handler was an interface. Edited my answer to include an actual authorization handler that handles both requirement types explicitly. – Adding multiple requirements to the same policy means that all those requirements have to be fulfilled. There is no way to make a policy have disjunct requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah that seems to make sense re multiple requirements per policy, I got that confused with the "multiple handlers" support. I need to go away and have a think about this. I'm trying to keep Identity Server down to a minimum, nothing app-specific, no authorization stuff (or very little). I'm new to most of these technologies so feeling around in the dark a little and getting wires crossed at almost every turn lol

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted because it has highlighted the problem with my approach to the authorisation stuff I'm doing. Going to read the MSDN docs on Claims-based Auth and reset.